# Permission error when I tried to move the files to different location

Tags: python

I'm doing a project and I'm having problems moving files into different subfolders. So for example, I have 2 files in the main folder, I want to read the first line, and if the first line has the word "Job", then I will move to the subfolder (main_folder/files/jobs). My code looks like this:

```
# Get all file names in the directory
def file_names():
    files = [file for file in listdir(source_dir) if file.endswith('csv')]
    return files

# Read files and separate them
def categorize_files(files):
    for file in files:
        with open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.readline().split(",")
            if 'Job ID' in text[0]:
                ## Problem Here ##
                move_files(file, 'jobs/')
                f.close()
                print("This is a job related file")
            else:
                print("no")

    return True

# Move files
def move_files(file_name, category):
    print(file_name)
    print(category)
    return shutil.move(source_dir + file_name, destination_dir + category + file_name)
```

So from my research, I'm guessing the file is still open (?) so I tried closing it. And move on, but somehow I end up having one file in the subfolder, and the original files still in the main folder. The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Muffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 557, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/Muffin/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/file_14.csv' -> 'C:/Users/Muffin/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/files/jobs/file_14.csv'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Muffin/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/file_organizer.py", line 38, in <module>
    categorize_files(files)
  File "C:/Users/Muffin/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/file_organizer.py", line 22, in categorize_files
    move_files(file, 'jobs/')
  File "C:/Users/Muffin/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/file_organizer.py", line 35, in move_files
    return shutil.move(source_dir + file_name, destination_dir + category + file_name)
  File "C:\Users\Muffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 572, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/Muffin/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/file_14.csv'
```

Can someone please explain why I'm having a problem? Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

++ I also tried closing the file. And even restart the computer and never opened any files. Still get the same error..

Comment: Un-indent your `if` block one level.  That will end the context block and close the file after reading the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you are trying to move a file while it is active and being read inside the `with` statement. The problem should be fixed if you un-indent the `if` statement by one layer. This should close the file and allow it to be moved. Here is the code:

```
# Read files and separate them
def categorize_files(files):
    for file in files:
        with open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.readline().split(",")
        if 'Job ID' in text[0]:
            ## Problem Here ##
            move_files(file, 'jobs/')
            f.close()
            print("This is a job related file")
        else:
            print("no")

    return True
```

Comment: Isn't it annoying when you comment the post with the correct answer, then see your comment displayed in an answer 3 seconds later?   Great minds...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is just to unindent the `if` block in your program.

```
# Get all file names in the directory
def file_names():
    files = [file for file in listdir(source_dir) if file.endswith('csv')]
    return files

# Read files and separate them
def categorize_files(files):
    for file in files:

        with open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.readline().split(",")

        if 'Job ID' in text[0]:
            ## Problem Here ##
            move_files(file, 'jobs/')
            f.close()
            print("This is a job related file")
        else:
            print("no")

    return True

# Move files
def move_files(file_name, category):
    print(file_name)
    print(category)
    return shutil.move(source_dir + file_name, destination_dir + category + file_name)
```

Although, I probably wouldn't have even used a `with` block for this application, just:

```
text = open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8').readline().split(",")
```

Edit: In my (somewhat perverse) love of one liners, the if statement could be reduced to:

```
if 'Job ID' in open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8').readline().split(",")[0]:
```

Share and Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you're trying to move move the file that you have open for reading inside the `with` statement. The following avoids that by moving the call to `move_files()` so it isn't called until the file has been closed.

```
# Read files and separate them
def categorize_files(files):
    for file in files:
        with open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.readline().split(",")
        if 'Job ID' in text[0]:
            move_files(file, 'jobs/')
            print("This is a job related file")
        else:
            print("no")

    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

Your file is being Used, Just close the program that it uses in the Taskmanager.